# What is the best method to limit rows for a specific user?

Tags: sql

I'm building an app where users (already in a different table) can have a set number of visitors they can invite to the location. What will be the best way to limit the number of rows (in the visitor table) for each user?

thanks for the advice.

Comment: Please show the query, table schemas, and desired output.

Comment: well, I am still considering the table design.

Comment: What I am considering is the columns [residentname, residentaddress, visitornumber, visitorcode, visitorname], and then in program I would manually index [visitornumber] and delete any rows that are above the set number. that seems like a little bit complex tho.

Comment: Put a constraint on column of # of visitors where it cannot be greater then a certain integer

Comment: or you could create a or those visitor attributes going to derive from another table as foreign keys?

Comment: The foreign key is kind of what I was thinking, (tho id have to refresh on how to use them), but I think using a constraint is probably a more efficient and simpler way to do it. I'm googling sql constraints now.

Comment: well. I suppose I could just do an "if number of rows returned", would be simple.

Comment: Which database are you using? Some databases can handle constraints and triggers others can't.

Comment: im on mssql server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest ***not*** handling this in the database schema. Instead, handle it in the [data model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_model).

Rule of thumb is to ***not*** enforce business rules into the schema; they change too often. Instead, the schema should enforce the integrity of the data. For example, the schema should make sure that every invitation is associated with an inviting user, the invited user, and an event. If any of those go away, the invitation should go away. That's protecting data integrity. A business rule is something like "names can only be 20 characters long" encouraging the overuse of something like `name varchar(20)`.

Instead, enforce the rule in your data model, something like `User.add_invitation`. This will be much easier to modify as the business rules change, it will provide better error messages for why attempting to add an invitation failed, and it will allow different applications with different rules to use the same schema.

This assumes that altering the database will go through one model. If you have code making changes to the database willy-nilly, it might be pragmatic to encode the business rules in one place: the schema.

---

You didn't say what database you're using, so I'm going to make a good decision for you and assume it's Postgres. It has great facilities for triggers and constraints. (I see you're on MS SQL Server, the code should be very similar.)

If you do decide to do this in the schema, you probably want a [`before insert` trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createtrigger.html) that [raises an exception](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html) if there's too many invitations.

Let's say you have a schema with users, events, and invitations.

```
create table users (
    id bigserial primary key,
    name text not null,
    ...whatever...
);

create table events (
    id bigserial primary key,
    ...whatever...
);

create table event_invitations (
    host     bigint references user(id),
    guest    bigint references user(id),
    event    bigint references events(id)
);
```

Each user can only invite 10 people to an event at a time. For that you'd use a `before insert` trigger to block the insert if there are already 10 invitations. My [pl/pgsql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-trigger.html) is a bit rusty, but it's something like this:

```
create function limit_event_invitations_to()
returns trigger as $$
declare
    invitations_count integer;
begin
    select count(*) into invitations_count
    from event_invitations
    where host = NEW.host and event = NEW.event;

    if invitations_count > TG_ARGV[0] then
        raise 'User %d has too many invitations to event %d', NEW.host, NEW.event
          using errcode = 'check_violation';
    end if;

    return NEW;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

create trigger limit_event_invitations
before insert on event_invitations
for each row execute procedure limit_event_invitations_to(10);
```

Basically do a count of how many invitations a user has already sent out for an event, and if it's above the limit raise an exception. This should be very fast since it's just indexed foreign key lookups.

I chose to use [the `check_violation` error code](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/errcodes-appendix.html) because it's the nearest equivalent to what you're doing. This lets you detect a particular type of exception without having to parse an error message.

Comment: I am using c# and mssql. 

I believe that I understand. At least I understand the concept, but let me ask a follow up question or two. What you are basically saying is that my tables need to hold whatever data could be necessary to hold. but I control that data programmably. That why I can always change the program, but If I restrict the data tables, I might not always be able to change those?

would my data tables be the database schema and my code the data model?

sorry if these are newb questions.

Comment: @birdseed Yeah, the tables and triggers and constraints and all that is the schema. That's all in SQL. The data model is your code that talks to the database and arranges the data into objects and provides methods. The goal is for the rest of the code to be *completely ignorant* of how the data is stored. If you want to add an invitation you don't do `insert into event_invitations ...` you call `event.add_invitation( host_user, guest_user)` and `Event.add_invitation()` does the `insert`. If you want to know what invitations a user has it might be `guests = event.guests( host_user )`.

Comment: I understand all but the last part. How do you create the event?

Comment: @birdseed You write an `Event.create` method that does `insert into events ...` and `Event.get` that does a `select * from events where ...` to get an existing event. Better is to use an [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) that handles the basic [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) and table relationships for you. You'd also use the ORM to declare and [manage your schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schema_migration). If you want more hands on help I can be reached through https://codementor.io/schwern